# Pulls out a gun from/Pulls a gun from/Pulls a gun out of

Tags: grammar, sentence-choice

1. Before anyone can say more, the old woman **pulls out a gun from** her purse and coldly shoots the man in the head.
2. Before anyone can say more, the old woman **pulls a gun from** her purse and coldly shoots the man in the head.
3. Before anyone can say more, the old woman **pulls a gun out of** her purse and coldly shoots the man in the head.

- Are all these versions correct? Which one do you prefer?
- Is the use of "coldly" okay? Is it placed correctly in the sentence?

Answer (score 0):

I would choose the second one as “from” sounds less clinical and a bit more elegant than “out of”. The fact that it was inside the purse and she pulled it out of the purse seems like almost extraneous information.

The first one actually a sounds a little comical for some reason, almost as if it’s normal for the average person to keep even several guns in their purse at one time; it’s as if she were pulling out small change or something. Perhaps this is just how it sounds to me in isolation.

The use of “coldly” is fine, and in this context means she displayed little or no emotion, as opposed to displaying “warmth” (kindness/empathy) in an emotional sense.

Answer (score -1):

#1 sounds awkward; it's technically grammatical but it isn't the way most people would phrase this line.

#2 and #3 are both valid and equally correct ways to phrase it. #2 is slightly more high-class and/or British to my ear, and #3 slightly more American and/or low-class. I'd probably use 'from' if I were writing an detached explanation of events, and 'out of' if I were writing a crime drama.

The use of "coldly" is fine, and that's exactly the right place for it.

Comment: Except if she were British she wouldn't pull it from her "purse" ( which is what we call a tiny bag in which coins and small objects are kept). She would pull it from her "handbag" which I think is what Americans call a purse. But a real woman wouldn't need a gun, she'd "hit him with her handbag" - a term popular at the time Margaret Thatcher was Prime Minister.

Comment: I didn't realize that American English was "low-class."

Comment: Really?  Imagine an extremely rich snob. Quick, what accent do they have? (But seriously, what I meant was if I'm thinking british vs american, "out of" feels more american; and if I'm thinking formal vs casual or high-class vs low-class, "out of" feels more like the latter.)

Comment: #1 is fine to me, although maybe less suitable to this specific context (where someone is shot). I'd say that "pulls a gun from her purse" suggests drawing and aiming it, but "pulls out a gun from her purse" would mean more generally taking it from her bag and holding it in some way or doing something with it.